# ¿Cual es el valor mas alto que le se puede asignar a la propiedad .Left de un objeto?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando mover objetos dentro de un Panel modificando la propiedad **.Left** de dichos objetos. 
El problema es que parece que cuando le asigno un **.Left** mas alto de 32768, el objeto no se mueve más. Sin embargo, el compilador no me da error...simplemente no asigna dicho valor y se queda "saturado" en el valor mas alto.

¿A alguien le ha pasado algo similar? ¿Puede estar relacionado con que la propiedad **.Left** sea de tipo int? ¿Alguien sabe arreglar esto?

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo!!
Un saludo!

Edito la pregunta añadiendo una captura de la ejecucion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la propiedad left es int32.. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.left?view=netframework-4.8 ... la documentacion no dice nada de nada respecto a tu problema.. podemos ver alguna clase de ejemplo?

Comment: Que yo sepa, no existe un método `left` en C#. Es posible que estés utilizando una extensión propia que tenga esta limitación. Ante la duda utiliza el método  `Substring`. [Documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Claro,gracias por vuestras respuestas. Os adjunto una captura de la ejecucion:

Comment: @RogerTorné creo que estas confundido esta hablando de la propiedad left de un control.. creo que estaba claro en su pregunta...

Comment: He tenido que editar la pregunta porque no la verdad es que no sabia como meter una captura en este comentario. En la captura podeis ver que el valor del Panel_Calendario_Tactical.Left es de -32768, y el de la parte derecha de la asignacion es de -34569, un valor "mayor". La captura se hizo despues de ejecutar dicha asignacion. Como veis, el valor de .Left parece saturarse...

Comment: Editar tu publicacion es lo correcto. Los comentarios son para pedir aclaraciones. Aclara todo en la pregunta.. ojo que el valor de left, tambien depende del valor de rigth... puede que uno este forzando al otro...

Comment: Vale, nunca habia usado el .Right. Como influyen uno en el otro? Supongo que al incrementar uno el otro disminuye?

Comment: de la documentacion: "Changes made to the Width and Left property values cause the Right property value of the control to change." o sea que al reves seria igual?? hay que leer la documentacion al respecto ;)

Comment: No se si es ese el motivo del fallo, pero creo que no, porque acabo de monitorizar el valor de .Right. Cuando .Left=-32768 el valor de .Right=3772 ...osea que aun le queda margen para no llegar a 0...

Comment: Acabo de intentar asignar la propiedad .Right...pero es de solo lectura

Comment: ¿Por qué precisas asignar un valor tan alto de .Left ?